# No funciona un ngFor en Angular, pero en otro html sí(del mismo proyecto)

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, angular, ngfor

estoy haciendo un proyecto en angular y a la hora de setear los datos que me trae una funcion en html, no funciona, creo que es por el ngFor, porque imprimo los datos que quiero setear en consola y si aparecen pero a la hora de traer los datos y ponerlos en html no devuelve nada, lo raro es que otro ngFor de otro componente sí funciona
el html es este`
Regresar

## Bienveni@, aquí puedes visualizar los eventos del Hotel

```
<img class="avatar" src="assets/jugadores-de-futbol.png"><br>
<table class="table table-dark table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Nombre de la Liga</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre del Equipo</th>
            <th scope="col">Puntos</th>
            <th scope="col">Goles a Favor</th>
            <th scope="col">Goles en Contra</th>
            <th scope="col">Diferencia de Goles</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <div *ngFor="let eq of equiposs">
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{eq._id}}</th>
                <td>{{eq.liga}}</td>
                <td>{{eq.nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{eq.puntos}}</td>
                <td>{{eq.golesFavor}}</td>
                <td>{{eq.golesContra}}</td>
                <td>{{eq.diferenciaGoles}}</td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

`
el ts que tengo es así
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

y el app.module está así
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

como resultado obtengo esto [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]

que si trae el dato en consola pero no en html
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXVVl.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mujey.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPai5.png

Comment: Ya declaraste el componente `ListaEquipos` en tu `AppModule`?

Comment: gracias, eso me faltaba

Answer (score 0):

Bien, el problema entonces es simplemente que no has declarado tu componente dentro del array de `declarations` de tu `AppModule`, por tanto, tu componente no tiene disponibles las directivas de `angular/common`.

Basta con añadirlo al array, y listo.